# same query different servers,different execution plan and time

Tags: sql-server-2008, execution-plan, performance, optimization, query-performance, performance-tuning

I have this query and it runs less than 2 minutes on Test but on Prod it takes 10 minutes.

Both are the same version,CPU,RAM,OS the same.

I have four tempdb files on Prod but one one Test.

I listed the time it took when I run each query one at a time. When I created missing indexes(2), it made it worse on test but reduce the execution time by half on prod.

I also see two different exec plans on Prod and Test.

```
select  distinct a11.APPLN_CODE  APPLN_CODE
into #ZZMQ00
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
where   a11.APPLN_DATE_KEY >=  99990000
```

Prod rows 390233 , 0 sec

Test rows 390178, 0 sec

```
select  distinct a12.APPLN_CODE  APPLN_CODE
into #ZZMQ01
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a12
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a13
      on    (a12.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a13.STATUS_KEY)
where   ((not ((a12.APPLN_CODE)
 in (select ps21.APPLN_CODE
    from    #ZZMQ00 ps21)))
 and a13.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS'))
```

Prod 49758 , 1 Sec

Test 49742 , 1 sec

```
select  a16.SCHOOL_KEY  SCHOOL_KEY,
    a15.DATE_KEY  DATE_KEY,
    a13.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY  DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY  ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a13.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY  OBJ_KEY,
    count(distinct a11.APPLT_KEY)  WJXBFS1
into #ZZMD02
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
    join    #ZZMQ01 pa12
      on    (a11.APPLN_CODE = pa12.APPLN_CODE)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a13
      on    (a11.APPLN_KEY = a13.APPLN_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_TERM    a14
      on    (a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a14.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.TRANS_TERM_STATUS_EFF_DATE_TO_DATE   a15
      on    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,a11.ROW_EFF_START_DTTM,112) = a15.EFFSTARTDATEKEY and 
    a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a15.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_DEPARTMENT   a16
      on    (a11.APPLN_DEPT_KEY = a16.DEPT_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    a17
      on    (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY = a17.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a18
      on    (a13.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a18.STATUS_KEY)
where   (((a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
 in (select r11.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY
    from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    r11
    where   r11.ACTIVE in ('1')))
 and a17.ACTIVE in ('1')
 and a18.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS')
 and a15.DATE_KEY <=  convert(varchar,a11.ROW_EFF_END_DTTM,112)
 and ((a15.DATE_KEY between LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 0921 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END and LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 1001 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END
 and a17.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'F')
 or (a17.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'X'
 and a15.DATE_KEY between LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0621 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END and LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0701 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END)
 or (a17.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'S'
 and a15.DATE_KEY between CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0428 END and CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0507 END)))
group by    a16.SCHOOL_KEY,
    a15.DATE_KEY,
    a13.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a13.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY
```

Prod 4851 rows, 27 sec prod,

test 4859 rows , 38 Sec

```
select  a17.SCHOOL_KEY  SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 10000)  DATE_KEY,
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY  DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY  ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY  OBJ_KEY,
    count(distinct a11.APPLT_KEY)  WJXBFS1
into #ZZMD03
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.TRANS_TERM_STATUS_EFF_DATE_TO_DATE   a12
      on    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,a11.ROW_EFF_START_DTTM,112) = a12.EFFSTARTDATEKEY and 
    a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a12.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_TERM    a13
      on    (a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a13.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    a14
      on    (a13.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY = (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY - 100))
    join    #ZZMQ01 pa15
      on    (a11.APPLN_CODE = pa15.APPLN_CODE)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a16
      on    (a11.APPLN_KEY = a16.APPLN_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_DEPARTMENT   a17
      on    (a11.APPLN_DEPT_KEY = a17.DEPT_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a18
      on    (a16.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a18.STATUS_KEY)
where   (((a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
 in (select r11.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY
    from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    r11
    where   r11.ACTIVE in ('1')))
 and a14.ACTIVE in ('1')
 and a18.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS')
 and a12.DATE_KEY <=  (convert(varchar,a11.ROW_EFF_END_DTTM,112) - 10000)
 and ((a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 0921 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 10000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 1001 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 10000)
 and a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'F')
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'X'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0621 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 10000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0701 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 10000))
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'S'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0428 END - 10000) and (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0507 END - 10000))))
group by    a17.SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 10000),
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY
```

Prod 4591 rows ,2 mintues:38 Seconds,

Test 4591 rows ,16 Sec

```
select  a17.SCHOOL_KEY  SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 20000)  DATE_KEY,
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY  DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY  ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY  OBJ_KEY,
    count(distinct a11.APPLT_KEY)  WJXBFS1
into #ZZMD04
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.TRANS_TERM_STATUS_EFF_DATE_TO_DATE   a12
      on    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,a11.ROW_EFF_START_DTTM,112) = a12.EFFSTARTDATEKEY and 
    a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a12.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_TERM    a13
      on    (a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a13.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    a14
      on    (a13.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY = (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY - 200))
    join    #ZZMQ01 pa15
      on    (a11.APPLN_CODE = pa15.APPLN_CODE)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a16
      on    (a11.APPLN_KEY = a16.APPLN_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_DEPARTMENT   a17
      on    (a11.APPLN_DEPT_KEY = a17.DEPT_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a18
      on    (a16.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a18.STATUS_KEY)
where   (((a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
 in (select r11.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY
    from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    r11
    where   r11.ACTIVE in ('1')))
 and a14.ACTIVE in ('1')
 and a18.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS')
 and a12.DATE_KEY <=  (convert(varchar,a11.ROW_EFF_END_DTTM,112) - 20000)
 and ((a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 0921 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 20000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 1001 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 20000)
 and a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'F')
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'X'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0621 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 20000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0701 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 20000))
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'S'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0428 END - 20000) and (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0507 END - 20000))))
group by    a17.SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 20000),
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY
```

Prod 3752 rows,  2 minutes 17 Seconds

Test 3752 rows, 14 sec

```
select  a17.SCHOOL_KEY  SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 30000)  DATE_KEY,
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY  DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY  ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY  OBJ_KEY,
    count(distinct a11.APPLT_KEY)  WJXBFS1
into #ZZMD05
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.TRANS_TERM_STATUS_EFF_DATE_TO_DATE   a12
      on    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,a11.ROW_EFF_START_DTTM,112) = a12.EFFSTARTDATEKEY and 
    a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a12.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_TERM    a13
      on    (a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a13.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    a14
      on    (a13.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY = (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY - 300))
    join    #ZZMQ01 pa15
      on    (a11.APPLN_CODE = pa15.APPLN_CODE)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a16
      on    (a11.APPLN_KEY = a16.APPLN_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_DEPARTMENT   a17
      on    (a11.APPLN_DEPT_KEY = a17.DEPT_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a18
      on    (a16.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a18.STATUS_KEY)
where   (((a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
 in (select r11.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY
    from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    r11
    where   r11.ACTIVE in ('1')))
 and a14.ACTIVE in ('1')
 and a18.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS')
 and a12.DATE_KEY <=  (convert(varchar,a11.ROW_EFF_END_DTTM,112) - 30000)
 and ((a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 0921 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 30000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 1001 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 30000)
 and a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'F')
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'X'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0621 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 30000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0701 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 30000))
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'S'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0428 END - 30000) and (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0507 END - 30000))))
group by    a17.SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 30000),
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY
```

Prod 2880 rows, 1 minutes and 38 seconds

Test 2880 rows, 12 Seconds

```
select  a17.SCHOOL_KEY  SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 40000)  DATE_KEY,
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY  DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY  ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY  OBJ_KEY,
    count(distinct a11.APPLT_KEY)  WJXBFS1
into #ZZMD06
from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a11
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.TRANS_TERM_STATUS_EFF_DATE_TO_DATE   a12
      on    (CONVERT(VARCHAR,a11.ROW_EFF_START_DTTM,112) = a12.EFFSTARTDATEKEY and 
    a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a12.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_TERM    a13
      on    (a11.APPLN_ACAD_TERM_KEY = a13.ACAD_TERM_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    a14
      on    (a13.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY = (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY - 400))
    join    #ZZMQ01 pa15
      on    (a11.APPLN_CODE = pa15.APPLN_CODE)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION  a16
      on    (a11.APPLN_KEY = a16.APPLN_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_DEPARTMENT   a17
      on    (a11.APPLN_DEPT_KEY = a17.DEPT_KEY)
    join    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_APPLICATION_STATUS   a18
      on    (a16.APPLN_STATUS_KEY = a18.STATUS_KEY)
where   (((a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY)
 in (select r11.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY
    from    BI_EDW.dbo.DIM_ACAD_REGULAR_TERM    r11
    where   r11.ACTIVE in ('1')))
 and a14.ACTIVE in ('1')
 and a18.STATUS_CD in ('DEP', 'SWD', 'SDE', 'SPD', 'MS')
 and a12.DATE_KEY <=  (convert(varchar,a11.ROW_EFF_END_DTTM,112) - 40000)
 and ((a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 0921 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 40000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0201) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 1001)) THEN 1001 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 40000)
 and a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'F')
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'X'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0621 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112)%10000 END - 40000) and (LEFT(a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,4)*10000+CASE WHEN ((CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 < 0301) OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 >= 0701)) THEN 0701 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)%10000 END - 40000))
 or (a14.ACAD_SEASON_SNAME = 'S'
 and a12.DATE_KEY between (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()-9,112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0428 END - 40000) and (CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) BETWEEN (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100-1)*10000+0701 AND (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000+0507 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) ELSE (a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY/100)*10000 + 0507 END - 40000))))
group by    a17.SCHOOL_KEY,
    (a12.DATE_KEY + 40000),
    a16.DGR_ADM_CAT_KEY,
    a14.ACAD_REGULAR_TERM_KEY,
    a16.APPLN_ACAD_LVL_KEY
```

Prod 2029 rows , 1:01 minutes,

Test 2029 rows , 10 Seconds

Comment: On Prod Table 'DIM_APPLICATION'. Scan count 9, logical reads 231976486 On Test Table 'DIM_APPLICATION'. Scan count 18, logical reads 43896

Comment: Production SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 1701 ms, elapsed time = 3398 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 470471 ms,  elapsed time = 110008 ms.

(2029 row(s) affected)

Comment: Test server

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 1607 ms, elapsed time = 1611 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 43100 ms,  elapsed time = 11570 ms.

(2029 row(s) affected)

Comment: @user42148 What is the `max memory` on test and PROD ? Are all `sys.configuration` settings same on test and PROD ?

Comment: @kin, Both 8 Core CPU, Prod 32GB RAM and Test 24GB RAM. Yes the sys configuration is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Folks,
I was able to resolve the issue by updating the statistics . I believe it is related to outdated stats and so the query optimizer getting not so efficient execution plan.
Thanks